# Save a file to Disk using Javascript/JQuery and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a javascript function which has a string s.

```
ABC,10
DEF,4
FRE,8
GTR,90
```

This is part of an ASP.NET -program. I understand that i have to invoke a C# function but i am not sure how to proceed further. Any pointers?

Comment: Who's disk are you trying to save to?  Server or client?  What form of data do you need to work with?

Comment: Server. The client changes the values 10,4,8,90 etc and then this needs to be saved to the server. I just need it to be  saved as a text file. Say, file.dat

Comment: Use $.ajax() and post the string to an api endpoint (or an Action) on your website (on server), then save it to disk via a something like a StreamWriter an File.CreateTextFile()

Comment: Do you have the code written to handle writing the file and you just need to know how to connect it to your ASP.NET infrastructure?  How much of this have you done?

Comment: i have the ASP.NEt code which handles quite a few get requests(Like getting JSON files etc). Till now the client just uses the website/server to view stuff. But now i need to add a functionality of client changing certain parameters like say temperature. And the calculations change based on the input parameters. I am creating a new controller for post data which takes the string as an argument and saves it to the disk. I am still figuring out this stuff. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MatsMagnem  i know that ` public IHttpActionResult ` can be used to get the results from server. What about POST?

Comment: @Morpheus An Action (IHttpActionResult) accepts a number of http actions. Like Get, Post, Patch, Delete and more. If you control the code within the action, you can basically du "whatever you want" (notice the quotes) :-)